# Polyglossia support for Mexican Spanish variant broken?

Tags: xetex, languages, polyglossia, spanish

*EDIT: Thanks to the issue linked by @moewe, I found out that the Mexican and Spanish versions of the Spanish Polyglossia module are identical except for a single word ("tabla" vs. "cuadro" for tables). So while I haven't solved this issue, it has ceased to be an issue -- I can use the default variant without issue.*

I'm using Polyglossia with XeLaTeX from TexLive 2020, and in spite of what the Polyglossia manual says, every attempt I've made to load the Mexican variant of Spanish fails. Some MWEs and the errors they produce follow...

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=mexican]{spanish}
```

This produces the following error:

```
Package xkeyval Error: `variant' undefined in families `spanish'. \setmainlanguage[variant=mexican]{spanish}
```

A second attempt, with a nearly identical command:

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=mexican]{spanish}
```

The same error appears:

```
Package xkeyval Error: `variant' undefined in families `spanish'. \setdefaultlanguage[variant=mexican]{spanish}
```

A third attempt is no more successful:

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}
\SetLanguageKeys{spanish}{variant=mexican}
```

This error is different:

```
Package xkeyval Error: `variant' undefined in families `spanish'. \setdefaultlanguage[variant=mexican]{spanish}
LaTeX3 Error: The key 'polyglossia/spanish/variant' is unknown and is being(LaTeX3) ignored. \SetLanguageKeys{spanish}{variant=mexican}
```

I have no idea why this is happening. Section 6.37 of the [Polyglossia manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/polyglossia/polyglossia.pdf) explicitly give `variant=mexican` as an option.

Comment: Two questions. First, what is wrong with Castilian Spanish? Second, you probably need to update your packages and ensure you have support for Spanish installed in your distribution. A minimal installation of TeX Live compiles your document just fine both in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @JairoA.delRio Castillian Spanish is an outlier in various things. They use guillemets instead of the English-style quotation marks used throughout Latin America, they hyphenate certain words differently (at-las vs. a-tlas), etc. As to my packages, I have the very latest full install of TexLive 2020.

Comment: Would it be possible to show us a complete example document that you tried to run? Something like https://gist.github.com/moewew/42f0bb4e4dfd0530d4d970ca8312a5ef I just managed to run that example without any errors on my machine. The `.log` file reports I have `polyglossia.sty 2020/12/08 v1.51`. Can you check your version of `polyglossia` in the `.log` file?

Comment: Only tangentially related, but there was https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/464 on the `polyglossia` bugtracker a few days ago: Apparently `variant=mexican` worked for everyone involved there.

Comment: show the log-file of a small example.

Comment: @moewe The issue you linked to had another bit of information that is highly relevant to this matter -- the two Spanish variants are 100% identical with the exception of a single word, which doesn't happen to be an issue for me. So as it turns out I don't need to use the Mexican variant, I'm going to close this.